# Has extremum or not?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm learning calculus and I have to do with functions 
$x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ where x!=0 and 0 when x=0 and $x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ where x!=0 and 0 when x=0

If I computed this well, both of them have derivatives in $x=0$ equal zero, so there could be extremum (for $x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x})$) or inflection point (for $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$). But in my opinion there aren't, because in any surroundings of $x=0$ we can find points which takes values $<0$ or $>0$, isn't it?

Comment: The derivative of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ at $x=0$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x_0)=0$  is only a *necessary* condition for a function $f$ to have an extremum at $x_0$ *provided it has a derivative*.

There is  a *sufficient* condition  to ensure a minimum or a maximum for a differentiable function:

Let $p>0$ the last order of derivation such that $\,f'(x_0)=\dots=f^{(p)}(x_0)=0\,$ (so that $f^{(p+1)}(x_0)\ne 0$) . If $p$ is odd, $f$ has a local extremum at $x_0$. If $p$ is even, $f$ has an inflection point at $x_0$. The extremum is a local minimum if $\,f^{(p+1)}(x_0)>0$, a local maximum if  $\,f^{(p+1)}(x_0)<0$.

For the functions in your post, they're differentiable at $0$ only once.  For functions like $\,x^n\sin \dfrac1x$, you can show by induction that when it is $p$ tiles differentiable at $0$, the derivatives of all order are $0$, so that you cannot conclude with this criterion.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^3$? $f^\prime(0)=f^{\prime\prime}(0)=0$ and $f^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)>0$, but $f$ doesn't have a minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to copy-paste the xhole of the explanation! Thanks for pointing it. Corrected now.

Comment: So, I could say that there is no extremum because second derivative doesn't exist?

Comment: No, since the second derivative test is only a sufficient condition. But your initial argument (in any neighbourhood of $0$, there are both negative and positive values) is perfectly correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you for whole explanation

Comment: nod here for erudition to the kuhn tucker conditions